# ulimit -n is not applied after simple restart

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, ubuntu-18.04, ulimit

For elasticsearch purpose I need to set *nofile* to 65536 (1024 default) but I can’t get it done

- ES is ran by workshop user, `htop` confirms it
- in `/etc/security/limits.conf` I have :

  ```
  * - nofile 65536
  ```
- in `/etc/pam.d/su` I have :

  ```
  session required pam_limits.so
  ```

After reboot, here is why I have in a terminal :

```
workshop@...$ ulimit -n
1024 
workshop@...$ sudo su 
[sudo]...
root@...$ su workshop 
workshop@...$ ulimit-n
65536
```

OR (just discovered that, after reboot also) :

```
workshop@...$ ulimit -n
1024 
workshop@...$ sudo su workshop
workshop@...$ ulimit-n
65536
```

Does the first login in the session doesn’t matter ? I don’t really understand what happens here

So I don’t have the value set initially but appears when I go through `root` user, so when I start ES it does not have the 65536 settings and I need it

I’m really ready to do what’s needed to solve this, but after read and made 3-4 answer found it still not works

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to reboot or re-login. Run the below code. This uses prlimit and will update the value of the current session (Bash) you are in. Try running the below script.

```
echo "add openfiles limit..........................."
sudo cp /etc/security/limits.conf  /etc/security/orig_limits.conf
sudo cat <<EOT >> /etc/security/limits.conf
*               hard    nofile          33000 
*               soft    nofile          33000
root            hard    nofile          33000 
root            soft    nofile          33000
EOT

sudo echo "session required pam_limits.so" > /etc/pam.d/common-session
sudo ulimit -n 33000
ulimit -u unlimited

update_ulimit_per_pid(){
    sudo echo "prlimit for pid "$pid" before updating is "$(ulimit -n)
    sudo echo "Updating ulimit for pid: "$pid
    sudo prlimit --pid $pid --nofile=33000:33000
    sudo echo "prlimit for pid "$pid" after updating is "$(ulimit -n)
}

for pid in `ps -ef | grep 'bash' | awk '{print $2}'` ; do update_ulimit_per_pid ; done
```

This should work. This will not only update ulimit when you relogin, but also the in the bash session you are in.

Comment: I'll be honest, I don't work on that anymore, nor I remember how I solved it. I won't be able to give any feedback on that answer

Comment: That's fine, may be it helps some other developer.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create file: `/etc/security/limits.d/90-nproc.conf` with value `* - nofile 65536`. Then do reboot or re-login. This file should change default value for this user.